# Why doesn't Mathematica simplify $\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)$?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

I'm new in mathematica, and there is a lot of things that I'm still missing...

I have this expression:
`A = SeriesData[\[Epsilon], 0, {
  R^2 (cos[\[Theta]]^2 + sin[\[Theta]]^2), 
   2 R (cos[\[Theta]]^2 + sin[\[Theta]]^2) ur[s]}, 0, 2, 1]`

So, when I "Simplify" it, I would expect to obtain R^2+2 R ur[x]... But I get the exact same thing...
How can I simplify this?

Comment: You misspelled `Sin` and `Cos`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace `cos` by [`Cos`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cos.html) and `sin` by [`Sin`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sin.html). Keep in mind that the in-built functions of Mathematica begin with a capital letter.

```
A = Simplify[SeriesData[\[Epsilon], 0, {R^2 (Cos[\[Theta]]^2 + Sin[\[Theta]]^2), 
    2 R (Cos[\[Theta]]^2 + Sin[\[Theta]]^2) ur[s]}, 0, 2, 1]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @ToniMendes, glad that helped.

Answer (score 2):

Better enter:

```
A = SeriesData[\[Epsilon], 
  0, {R^2 (Cos[\[Theta]]^2 + Sin[\[Theta]]^2), 
   2 R (Cos[\[Theta]]^2 + Sin[\[Theta]]^2) ur[s]}, 0, 2, 1]
```

Then [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html) works. The problem is, in Mathematica [`Sin`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sin.html) and [`Cos`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cos.html) represent sine and cosine and not sin and cos.

Your result with Mathematica is:

```
SeriesData[\[Epsilon], 0, {R^2, 2 R ur[s]}, 0, 2, 1]
```

after using [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
{R^2 (Cos[\[Theta]]^2 + Sin[\[Theta]]^2), 
  2 R (Cos[\[Theta]]^2 + Sin[\[Theta]]^2) ur[s]} // Simplify

(*  {R^2, 2 R ur[s]}   *)
```

Have fun!